# How to deploy spring boot + angular 7 + mariadb apps on heroku?

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, deployment, mariadb, angular7

I have spring boot app with frontend as angular 7 and database and mariaDb. 
How can I deploy my website on heroku (Production) ?
Is there any other platform or service available, like AWS (but free) where I can do this?

Comment: "free"?  Do you have your own server?  And it is accessible from the Web?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has both Java and NodeJS buildpacks, which would allow you to deploy the
Spring Boot and (in case you want to deploy the frontend separately) the Angular7 framework. They even have a tutorial specific for [Spring Boot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku).

Regarding the database, Heroku allow you to configure storage through Add-ons.
So you would have to add an Add-on for MariaDB.
The one I found available is [this one](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb-maria) which have a free tier.
But notice the limits: 10 connections and 5 MB of storage.

So I think you can deploy with Heroku and use both the servers and the DB without any cost initially. But on this tier, the Dynamo would sleep after 30 minutes as you can check on the [pricing page](https://www.heroku.com/pricing).

Finally, Heroku also support configuring domains into the app without costs, but it will be necessary to input credit card info.

Hope this helped!